# get_day_link() is not working accurately in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my code

This piece of code is inside of my loop

```
<a href="<?php echo get_day_link( get_the_time('Y'), get_the_time('m'), get_the_time('d')); ?>"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></a>
```

It is displaying "Oops! That page can’t be found."

But if I write like this (I mean (year, month, day) variables out of the loop)

```
<?php

     $archive_year  = get_the_time( 'Y' ); 
     $archive_month = get_the_time( 'm' ); 
     $archive_day   = get_the_time( 'd' ); 

<?

<?php if( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
   <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_day_link( $archive_year, $archive_month, $archive_day ) ); ?>">
      <?php _e( 'This day’s posts', 'textdomain' ); ?>
   </a>
<?php endwhile; endif;?>
```

It takes me to the right page but with a static day (19), where the day is 20.

N.B. ***This is a custom post. ***If I use only year(2018) and month(01) it works fine.

The problem is day.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding date variables inside the loop( after the_post() ).